# Is GMP built into GCC?

Tags: gcc, gmp

You need GMP to build GCC from source. Does that mean that GCC has built-in arbitrary precision arithmetic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GCC uses GMP at *compile-time*.

I believe that one of the reason may be that some language standard (probably Fortran90, but probably not C99) requires arithmetic of constant expressions to be computed with "infinite" precision. So if a source code contains `1234567890*9876543210*123098456876`  that should be (at least for some dialects of Fortran?) computed in full. For that GCC uses GMP.

Don't think that a GCC compiled program can do [bignum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bignum) arithmetic (at run time) without linking a bignum library like Gmp.

And you could try CommonLisp, e.g. [SBCL](http://www.sbcl.org/). It gives you bignum arithmetic with interactive dynamic compilation.